# How do I put two integers together in a print function without adding them in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a guess the number game in python.

```
print("I am thinking of a number between" + lowerboundnumber +" and" +greaterboundnumber)

lowerboundnumber = random.randint(1, 50)
greaterboundnumber = random.randit(51, 100)
```

How can I use my variables, lowerboundnumber and greaterboundnumber in a print function, without adding them?
Sorry what I am trying to ask makes no sense. But any type of help would do

Comment: Are you trying to add them together and print the result, or you don't want to use `"string" + numbr +"string" + number` syntax when you print?

Comment: Also you are using random.randit instead of random.ranint on line 4

Comment: Use a string formatting method.

Comment: please add more information about what you want to do

Comment: As long as you don't use a math operation between the two ints, you should be able to print them

Comment: The code you've written doesn't try to add the two numbers. It will get an error because you can't add a string and an integer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  You need to repeat your tutorial materials on basic data types and on formatting output.  I suspect that you simply need to look up the `str` conversion method ... which gets your question deleted as inappropriate for this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) formatting and make it quite a bit cleaner:

`print(f"I am thinking of a number between {lowerboundnumber} and {greaterboundnumber}")`